# Apply multiple client-side filters with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I need some help with jQuery filtering and selection.
I've got a list of elements

```
<ul>
    <li data-cat="1 4 6" data-level="1 2" data-price="500">Element 1</li>
    <li data-cat="1 2 5" data-level="1 3" data-price="300">Element 2</li>
    <li data-cat="2 4 6" data-level="3" data-price="450">Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

which I must filter client-side (show/hide).
Category filter is a radiobutton (single selection), price filter is a jQuery UI slider, level filter is a set of checkboxes (multiple selection). These 3 controls affect the following variabiles:

```
var filterCategory = 0;
var filterPriceFrom = 0; var filterPriceTo = 0;
var filterLevel = [];
```

On them changing I call the following listener, which applies the filters (leve filter not implemented yet).

```
var list = $('ul > li');
list.hide();

if (filterCategory > 0){
    list = $('ul > li[data-cat~=\"' + filterCategory + '\"]');
}

list = list.filter(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    return value >= filterPriceFrom && value <= filterPriceTo;
});

list.show();
```

Now I have to add level filtering, which is a set of checkboxes (multiple selection). I think I have 2 options

1: add a block like category filter. The problem with this solution is that my filtered result are within "list" variabile. I would like to use the power of jQuery data() selector. How can I take "list" variabile (and not the entire DOM) in input and apply filters again?

```
$(list > data-level[...]) /* ??? */
```

2: Put everything inside list.filter() block. Again: how can I keep using jQuery data() selector?

```
 list = list.filter(function() {

    /* check if $(this) has filterCategory within data-cat attribute */

    /* check if $(this) has at least one of filterLevel elements within data-level attribute */

    var value = parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    return value >= filterPriceFrom && value <= filterPriceTo;
});
```

Thank you.